# Add proxy on Injectable

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, proxy

I have a AngularTS front-end, with a service `SaveService`

I would like to add a Proxy on it. I did not find a lot of documentation about it.
I tried naive implementation :

```
export class SaveService {
  private proxyService: SaveService | null = null;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const originalService = this.injector.get(SaveService);
    const proxyService = new Proxy<SaveService>(originalService, {
      get: (target, prop: keyof SaveService, receiver) => {
        console.log(`Calling method: ${prop}`);
        return target[prop];
      },
    });

  }
}
```

But it cannot works like this because `this.injector.get(SaveService)` is a *Circular dependency*

Any ways to add a proxy on this injectable service ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My first goal in to learn how to use proxy. In the case of this project i would like to set a proxy to achieve this goal : My app is using Firebase auth, but the auth is loaded too late if user reach my page via direct url, the request is made before and fail. I would like my proxy to : 1 - Check auth and allow request if true. 2- If not, wait until true.  3 - on timeout go to Homepage.

Comment: But in the example i am just trying to add a proxy which log the called method of my service, to be sure i can add a proxy on a injectable service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean by using proxy, but in Angular world this would be called an [Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor). Its job is to intercept the requests and do some stuff with them, usually to append some headers or do logging.

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  public intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('REQUEST:', req),
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap((res: HttpResponse<any>) => console.log('RESPONSE:)', res),
    );
  }
}
```

In your case, it might look like this:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  // Let's pretend that's how your auth service is called
  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService)

  public intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Check if user is authenticated
    if (firebaseService.isAuthenticated()) {
      // if so, continue
      return next.handle(req);
    } else {
      // If not, authenticate and contine
      return firebaseService.authenticate().pipe(
        map(() => next.handle(req))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

So your interceptor check if user is logged in and if not, it'll call the authenticate method and when it's successful it continues with original request. You can also add AUTH headers and so on... But take this code as an example and adjust it to your own needs.

Comment: Thats seems to do what i would like. In the mean time, i solved this by using a Guard on the whole page who wait for login, so i suppose all my call on service are safe and i dont need to check again. But thx for teaching me about interceptor